# Get employee with on-off-on weekend work pattern

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an employee table which has columns like
employee_ID, punch_in_date, punch_out_date.

Now, what I need is to find those employees who have worked on-off-on weekend pattern.

It is like if an employee has worked in week1 then he/she should not have worked in week2 and must have worked in Week3.
Week1, week2, and week3 are the consecutive weekend days.

I tried using the lag function of sql.

```
    SELECT   employee_id, 
         punch_in_date, 
         Lag(punch_in_date) OVER(partition BY employee_id ORDER BY employee_id)                              AS week_lag,
         Datediff(day,Lag(punch_in_date) OVER(partition BY employee_id ORDER BY employee_id) ,punch_in_date) AS days
FROM     employee 
WHERE    Datediff(day,Lag(punch_in_date) OVER(partition BY employee_id ORDER BY employee_id) ,punch_in_date)>= 14
AND      datediff(day, punch_in_date, 'Today's date') <= 90 /*This means the data must falls under 3 months duration*/;
```

But I am getting an error like

> SQL Error [4108] [S0001]: Windowed functions can only appear in the
>   SELECT or ORDER BY clauses.

How can I get the required result?

sample data:

```
employee_ID |punch_in_date |punch_out_date |
------------|--------------|---------------|
2           |2015-12-05    |2015-12-05     |
2           |2015-12-12    |2015-12-12     |
2           |2015-12-19    |2015-12-19     |
2           |2016-01-02    |2016-01-02     |
2           |2016-01-23    |2016-01-24     |
2           |2016-01-24    |2016-01-25     |
2           |2016-01-30    |2016-01-30     |
2           |2016-02-06    |2016-02-06     |
2           |2016-02-06    |2016-02-06     |
2           |2016-02-06    |2016-02-07     |
2           |2016-02-13    |2016-02-14     |
2           |2016-02-27    |2016-02-28     |
2           |2016-03-12    |2016-03-13     |
```

Comment: Thank you. I tagged and its sql -server.

Comment: Using `datediff(day, punch_in_date, GETDATE()) <= 90` will prevent SQL Server from using any indexes on the `punch_in_date` column.   Using `punch_in_date >= dateadd(day,-90,getdate()` will provide the same functionality without preventing index use.  This is known as [sargability](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/799584/what-makes-a-sql-statement-sargable)

Comment: It would be nice if you could add some sample data and expected result as well

Comment: I have edited the question with the sample data of an employee @holder

Comment: @Alesh What's your expected result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you want:

```
select employee_id,  punch_in_date, week_lag        
       datediff(day, week_lag, punch_in_date) AS days
from (select e.*,
             lag(punch_in_date) over (partition by employee_id order by employee_id) as week_lag
      from employee e
     ) e
where week_lag >= 14 and
      datediff(day, punch_in_date, getdate()) <= 90 ;
```

When using window functions, be very careful about `where` filtering.  The filters are applied *before* the window function, so you might miss some rows that you want.

Answer (score 1):

As the error message states; Windowed function are only allowed in select and order by. 
What you can do is to use your query in a subquery

```
Select Employee_id,punch_in_date, week_lag,[days] FROM(
 SELECT   employee_id, 
         punch_in_date, 
         Lag(punch_in_date) OVER(partition BY employee_id ORDER BY employee_id)                              
AS week_lag,
         Datediff(day,Lag(punch_in_date) OVER(partition BY employee_id ORDER BY 
employee_id) ,punch_in_date) AS [days]
FROM     employee 
where punch_in_date >= dateadd(day,-90,getdate())
) q
WHERE    [days]>= 14
```

Comment: Using `datediff(day, punch_in_date, GETDATE()) <= 90` will prevent SQL Server from using any indexes on the `punch_in_date` column.   Using `punch_in_date >= dateadd(day,-90,getdate()` will provide the same functionality without preventing index use.  This is known as [sargability](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/799584/what-makes-a-sql-statement-sargable)

Comment: I am getting error Incorrect syntax near where while running this query. @holder

Comment: @Alesh MS SQL requires that a sub-query has an alias.  So just put an alias name like f.e. `q` after the round bracket.

Comment: @holder Perhaps that criteria for `punch_in_date` could be put in the sub-query. It might improve the performance of the query.